# Is there a method to factor equations with two variables raised to the second power?

Tags: quadratics

I found the equation $2b^2-ab-a^2=0$ on a problem and couldn't find a way to factor it. Is there any method to factor these types of equations?

Comment: You can consider that $a$ is fixed and that the expression $2b^2-ab-a^2=p(b)$ as a polynomial in $b$. $p$ has an obvious zero, so you can factor it.

Comment: Put another way, the discriminant is a square, $9.$  That means it factors nicely, integer coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do it is by defining a variable $u=\frac{a}{b}$ and then dividing by $b^2$ on both sides (assuming $b\neq 0$). We will then get a quadratic in $u$ e.g.
$$2b^2-ab-a^2=0$$
$$2-\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a^2}{b^2}=0$$
$$2-u-u^2=0$$
$$u^2+u-2=0$$
$$(u+2)(u-1)=0$$
$$u=1,-2$$
$$a=b,-2b$$
We also have the potentially singular solution that results when $b=0$. We can easily see that the only solution of that form is $a,b=0$, which is included in our general solution.

Another method to solve these types of equations where all terms are order $2$ is to consider one variable as a "constant" and solve using quadratic formula (or if you are bold, you can try for a factorization). For example, if we treat $b$ as a constant in the example you provided,
$$a^2+ba-2b^2=0$$
$$a=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+8b^2}}{2}$$
$$a=\frac{-b\pm 3b}{2}$$
$$a=b,-2b$$
This will be pretty similar in terms of difficulty as the former method. This method also has applications when solving equations in two variables where the equation is, say, a quartic in one variable and a quadratic in the other. You can treat the quartic variable as a constant and solve using quadratic equation. I can't find any examples at the moment, but I'll add them later.